# Nonzero Entries Modulo prime in Pascal's Triangle

Tags: number-theory

**Prove that for an integer $n$ written in base $p$ as 

                  $$n = n_0 + n_1p +n_2p^2 + \dots + n_sp^s$$
that the number of entries in the $nth$ of Pascal's triangle that are not divisible by $p$ is given by 

                  $$ \prod_{k=0}^{s} ( 1 + n_k) = (1 + n_0)(1 + n_1)(1+n_2)\dots(1+n_s)$$**

*I see the connection to Kummer's theorem, but am not sure of how to extend the ideas there to obtain this 'formula'.*